# Unable to load configuration

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I am trying to deploy struts+spring+hibernate app on tomcat server, but there occurs some error with struts configuration, namely in struts.xml I am using a bean `editEmployeeAction` defined on spring.xml, but while deploying the app, the tomcat failed to load the action [not found action]

please help me to solve the problem!

**spring.xml**

```
   ...
   <!-- This bean has been referred fron struts.xml file; So type it correctly; -->
   <!-- Make scope prototype; This is really important. -->
   <bean id="editEmployeeAction" class="me.modernpage.controller.EditEmployeeAction" 
    scope="prototype">
    <property name="employeeManager">
        <ref bean="employeeManager"/>
    </property>
  </bean>   

  <bean id="employeeDAO" class="me.modernpage.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref bean="sessionFactory"/>
    </property>
  </bean>
   <bean id="employeeManager" class="me.modernpage.service.EmployeeManagerImpl">
    <property name="employeeDAO">
        <ref bean="employeeDAO"/>
    </property>
   </bean> 
   ...
```

**struts.xml** located on src/

```
<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<constant name="struts.custom.i18n.resources" value="messages" />
<constant name="struts.enable.SlachesInActionNames" value="true" />

<package name="default" namespace="" extends="struts-default">
    <!-- Two things to Notice: 
         1) class is set to 'editEmployeeAction' which is bean defined by Spring context
         2) We have given the method to be called here as well; -->
    
    <action name="list" class="editEmployeeAction" method="listEmployees">
        <result>/view/editEmployeeList.jsp</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="add" class="editEmployeeAction" method="addEmployee">
        <result type="redirect">/list</result>
    </action>
    
    <action name="delete/*" class="editEmployeeAction" method="deleteEmployee">
        <param name="employee.id">{1}</param>
        <result type="redirect">/list</result>
    </action>
    <action name="*" class="editEmployeeAction" method="listEmployees">
        <result>/view/editEmployeeList.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

here, as you can see the value of 'class' is ediEmployeeList bean, then i think the tomcat can't find this bean?!

**error:**

```
23:06:57,021 ERROR Dispatcher:42 - Dispatcher initialization failed
```

Unable to load configuration. - action - file:/home/yusuf/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/web/Spring_Struts_Hibernate/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:17:73
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:70)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.getContainer(Dispatcher.java:978)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:446)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:490)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.InitOperations.initDispatcher(InitOperations.java:74)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.init(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:57)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:251)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4533)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5172)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: Action class [editEmployeeAction] not found - action - file:/home/yusuf/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/web/Spring_Struts_Hibernate/WEB-INF/classes/struts.xml:17:73
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.verifyAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:486)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addAction(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:429)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.addPackage(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:556)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:295)
at org.apache.struts2.config.StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.loadPackages(StrutsXmlConfigurationProvider.java:112)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:264)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:67)
... 38 more

Comment: Kindly resolve this first: `Caused by: Action class [editEmployeeAction] not found`

Comment: I tried to discover all the causes of this statement, didn't find a clue

Comment: Can you add more details to the question such as web.xml

Comment: @RomanC no problem with web.xml, i solved the problem by putting the struts2-spring-plugin.jar file on the class path, thanks bro for the attention

Answer (score 0):

finally, i realized the cause of the problem , the project lacks struts-spring-plugin library to link struts and spring each other.

[strust2-spring-plugin](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/org.apache.struts/struts2-spring-plugin/2.5.16/source-code)